# Config for server and datacenter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Host
belongs_to :data_centers
has_one :data_center

DataCenter
has_many :hosts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Host has a data_center_id, then the correct association is:

```
class Host < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :data_center
end
```

Note the pluralization, and remove the `has_one`.